# Is there any symbol for exponentiation series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, exponentiation

Summation series uses the Sigma symbol like this.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 2$$

Product Series uses the Pi symbol like this.

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4n^2}{4n^2 - 1} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

What about exponentiation series? Does this exist? What symbol is used for it? E.g., the series starts at n=1 and goes to infinity, and the term prototype is just n, would yield this:

$$1^{2^{3^{...}}}$$

Obviously that doesn't converge, but I just wanted to show some example.

Are exponentiation series studied in math? I would like to read more about them.

**Note:** I saw the tag for power series, but it does not appear to be what I want. E.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351831/power-series-and-power-series-expansion) is a summation series.

Comment: I don't know that there's a standard equivalent of $\sum$ or $\prod$ for exponentiation; but see [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) or [power tower](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html).

Comment: What about the up arrow $\uparrow$?

Answer (score 1):

While there is no ''standard'' notation, as you describe, that is analogous to the sigma and pi notations, you may use [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) instead.

This notation uses $\uparrow$ to denote exponentiation, $\uparrow\uparrow$ do denote tetration, $\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow$ to denote pentation, and so forth. For instance, 
$$
{\displaystyle 2\uparrow 4=2\times (2\times (2\times 2))=2^{4}=16},
$$
and
$$
{\displaystyle 2\uparrow \uparrow 4=2\uparrow (2\uparrow (2\uparrow 2))=2^{2^{2^{2}}}=65536}.
$$